# how to extract ptx from cuda exe and some related cuda compiler questions

Tags: cuda, gpu

1)I want to extract ptx code from a CUDA exe and use that kernel code in another program . 
Is there a way to identify the kernel ptx code from an exe. I know they are arbitrarily laid out in an exe file data section.

I learnt that in MAC executables the ptx kernels start with .version and ends with a null string. Is there something like that for win exe(PE) files. I guess  i need to parse the exe file , gather ptx statements one at a time and group them together as kernels. But I dont know how i would go about it. some help would get me started. I also find a .nvFatBi section in Cuda exe. What is that supposed to be?

2)I also learnt that there are global constructors  which register the cubin with the cuda runtime. I dont understand this part completely. Does the function cudaRegisterFatBinary come into play here. If so how can I use this ptx to supply the pointer to the cudaRegisterFatBinary ? I understand i have to compile the ptx to cubin file . is it possible programatically? In short i want to emulate the nvcc itself in some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: cuobjdump --dump-ptx [executable-name]

Comment: Thank you very much! but how do i do this programatically? any ideas? and could you also show me some way to do the stuff i mentioned in my second question.

Comment: @ash can't you call this tool using `system()` ?